# sum values of selected options with initial value

Tags: javascript, jquery

im using this script to do what i need:

**HTML**

```
<label id="starting_price">45.00</label>
<select name="price" >
<option value="">Options</option>
<option value="4.00">Small</option>
<option value="8.00">Medium</option>
</select>
```

**EXAMPLE#1**

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
     $("#starting_price").html(sum);
});
```

The problem im facing is that i want the initial value to be from a label:

**EXAMPLE#2**

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var initial = $('#starting_price').html();
    var sum = initial;
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
     $("#starting_price").html(sum);
});
```

i notice this did not work and it was because it needed to convert the string into a integer so i used this:

**EXAMPLE#3**

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var initial = +($('#starting_price').html());
    var sum = initial;
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
     $("#starting_price").html(sum);
});
```

this are the results:

**EXAMPLE#1**

Starts from $0.00 if i select a option (example: $4.00) the result is $4.00 if i select the option with no value the result goes back to $0.00.

**EXAMPLE#2**

NOT WORKING

**EXAMPLE#3**

Starts from $45.00 if i select a option (example: $4.00) the result is $49.00 if i select the option with no value the result stays in $49.00 when it should go back to $45.00.

How can i make EXAMPLE#3 go back to initial price if option selected is NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a html5 attribute:

```
<label id="starting_price" data-startprice="45.00">45.00</label>
```

You can access this with one of these:
`$('#starting_price')[0].dataset.startprice` (this is native JS, my preferred) or
`$('#starting_price').attr('data-startprice')` or  `$('#starting_price').data('startprice')`

Because this doesnt change, you can always get back to it

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var sum = Number( $('#starting_price')[0].dataset.startprice );// get the data-attribute
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number( $(this).val());
    });
     $("#starting_price").html(sum);
});
```

Here you can find some [documentation on data attribute with javascript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

You could store the initial value in a data attribute:

```
<label id="starting_price" data-initialvalue="45.00">45.00</label>
<select name="price">
    <option value="">Options</option>
    <option value="4.00">Small</option>
    <option value="8.00">Medium</option>
</select>
```

Then access that:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var initial = +($('#starting_price').data("initialvalue"));
    var sum = initial;
    $('select :selected').each(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $("#starting_price").text(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 var initial = +($('#starting_price').html());
$('select').change(function(){
    //var initial = +($('#starting_price').html());
    var sum = initial;
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
     $("#starting_price").html(sum);
      sum=initial;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kBMM5/)

Comment: This would work in this situation. However, if there are (lets say) two of these dropdowns, this wont work anymore, but I like the global scopte variable, I was thinking about the same at first